# How do you change the color of an icon and text in a TextView for the navigationDrawer?

Tags: android, material-design

I'm trying to follow the material design guidelines, but I don't know how to change the color of the icon and text for the navigation drawer.

(Scroll down to Selection State):
http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#navigation-drawer-content

This is from my MainActivity (in onCreate()):

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    ListAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, menu, imageID);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            mAdapter.setSelectedItem(position);
        }
    });
   ...
   }
```

from MyAdapter():

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

private Integer[] imageID;
private int mSelectedItem;

public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] menu, Integer[] imageID) {
    super(context, R.layout.row_layout, menu);
    this.imageID = imageID;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);

    String menu = getItem(position);
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView.setText(menu);

    if (position == getSelectedItem()) {
        textView.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.primaryColor));
    }
    else {
        textView.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.navDrawerTextColor));
    }

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageID[position]);

    return view;
}

public int getSelectedItem() {
    return mSelectedItem;
}

public void setSelectedItem(int selectedItem) {
    mSelectedItem = selectedItem;
}
```

}

and my TextView from xml file:

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
    android:paddingStart="72dp"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/color_selector"
    android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

EDIT: I used a color_selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/primaryColor" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:color="@color/primaryColor" android:state_selected="true" />
    <!-- selected -->
    <item android:color="#DE000000" />
    <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

But when the item is selected, it doesn't permanently stay that color

Comment: you can use `android:textColor="#DE000000"` to change the text color and for Icon, use icon image in same color you want or try `tint` property in android 5

Comment: is it that textview you are trying to change its color? if you have reference to it what prevents you?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a [NavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html), part of the [Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) that does all of the item selection and styling of the navigation drawer for you.